# Rotate Webpage Via Code w/ Button

Tags: rotation, html

Before you down vote, I know this question has been asked but I have a different twist to the question. Here is the original stack-overflow question, once read, I will post my twist at the end.

*"I'm hoping that there's a relatively simple way to rotate a webpage a little bit, 30 degrees or so, while still leaving it fully functional and usable.
I completely control the page, and can modify it to make this easier if needed. I'd rather not re-write the whole thing in SVG, though, but perhaps javascript and CSS/HTML will work?
Is there a way using CSS, Javascript, or some other cross browser method that would allow me to accomplish this?"*

**Twist:** I have the code that rotates only -30 degrees once (which is written in HTML). I will like to have a button where once you press it, it will rotate the webpage by -30 degrees more than what it is currently at. Appreciate it.

Code (that is static in turning the webpage):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.86602540, M12=0.50000000, M21=-0.50000000, M22=0.86602540,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.0, M12=0.50000000, M21=-0.50000000, M22=0.86602540,sizingMethod='auto expand');
      -moz-transform:  matrix(0.86602540, -0.50000000, 0.50000000, 0.86602540, 0, 0);
      -webkit-transform:  matrix(0.86602540, -0.50000000, 0.50000000, 0.86602540, 0, 0);
      -o-transform:  matrix(0.86602540, -0.50000000, 0.50000000, 0.86602540, 0, 0);
  }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Testing</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html">Matrix calculator here</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for rotation on button click.

Hope below code will help you.

```html
<html>
  <body onLoad="rotate()">
    <div class="rot">
    <p>Testing</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html">Matrix calculator here</a></p>
    <button id="btn">Rotate</button>
    </div>
    
    <script>
 var initial_rotation=0;
 var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
 var rotateDiv=document.querySelector(".rot");
 
  
 btn.addEventListener("click",rotate);
 function rotate(){
  initial_rotation -=30;
  rotateDiv.style.WebkitTransform="rotate(" + initial_rotation + "deg)";
  rotateDiv.style.msTransform="rotate(" + initial_rotation + "deg)";
  rotateDiv.style.transform="rotate(" + initial_rotation + "deg)";
 }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap your elements inside a div and add a class to this div. Use the above JS snippets.